# Print numbers in sequence using threads and lambdas in Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency, java-threads

I came across code to print numbers in sequence using two threads in Java. Here's the code

```
public class ThreadPrint {
    public static boolean isOdd = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable even = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10;)
                if (!isOdd) {
                    System.out.println("Even thread = " + i);
                    i = i + 2;
                    isOdd = !isOdd;
                }
        };
        Runnable odd = () -> {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10;)
                if (isOdd) {
                    System.out.println("odd thread = " + i);
                    i = i + 2;
                    isOdd = !isOdd;
                }
        };

        Thread e = new Thread(even);
        Thread o = new Thread(odd);

        e.start();
        o.start();
    }
}
```

My question here is if I increment i as i+=2 in the loop itself like

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i+=2)
```

I get an output as **Even thread= 0** and then the program stops execution. How is this thread and lambda getting this job done in the earlier style of for loop where the incrementation is inside a condition but why not in the loop declaration line itself?

Comment: It's called a race condition: Try increasing from `10` to `100000`.

Comment: @MAnouti even if I make it to 10000 it works fine. Why is that it behaves differently when I increment in different ways(one in loop declaration line and the other in the condition in the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i <= 10;)` will not increment the variable `i`, hence acting as an infinite loop. Your code is not thread-safe, there is no synchronization on the accessing of `isOdd` between the two threads. However, since the loop is *infinite*, each thread will eventually pass the `if(isOdd)` or `if(!isOdd)` five times and print the values.

When the increment is placed in the `for` loop, most of the `if` checks will fail as threads are not synchronized, while there are only five attempts for each thread.